# Use Grizzly transparently under the hood?

Tags: java, open-source, frameworks, glassfish, nio

Is there a way to bind [grizzly](https://grizzly.dev.java.net/) dynamic/transparent to my Java Applications (maybe by using spring)? Or is the IO handling part of the Web Container (eg. Glassfish)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean dynamically creating/destroying grizzly instances in your java application? Yes it is possible. Web Container isn't required for such thing.